# Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project? --- Firebase with Flutter and Visual Studio code

Tags: firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have XCode installed because flutter doctor required it but I am not using it.

I am using VSCode.
In VSCode where am I supposed to put this file called `GoogleService-Info.plist`?

The project uses Flutter and Firebase.

This is the error:

`Exception has occurred. FirebaseException ([core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VSCode, follow this steps

1. Right click on **ios** folder
2. Choose **Open in Xcode**
3. Select **Runner > Runner** and right click
4. Choose **Add Files to ‘Runner’**
5. Select your **GoogleService-Info.plist** and press **Add**

And configure firebase in `AppDelegate.swift` file like this

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase  /// 1. ADD THIS LINE

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure() /// 2. ADD THIS LINE
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
 
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to the project by following these steps from the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios/#installing-your-firebase-configuration-file):

> 1. Using Xcode, open the project's ios/{projectName}.xcworkspace file. Right click Runner from the left-hand side project navigation
>    within Xcode and select "Add files".
> 2. Select the GoogleService-Info.plist file you downloaded, and ensure the "Copy items if needed" checkbox is enabled.

Answer (score -3):

Go to your "projectName">android>app and dump the file in this directory.